# Unable to read value on DOM element with Stimulus

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I'm using Stimulus in my project.  I have the following HTML:

```html
<form id="subscriptionForm" data-controller="subscription-form" action="/subscriptions">  
  <input type="hidden" name="product" data-subscription-form-target="product">

  <div data-subscription-form-tier-value="Production" data-subscription-form-target="tier"></div>
  <div data-subscription-form-tier-value="Test" data-subscription-form-target="tier"></div>
</form>
```

I have multiple `tier` targets.  I also have this JS:

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["tier"]

  connect() {
    this.tierTargets.forEach((element) => {
      console.log(element)
      console.log(element.tierValue)
    })
  }
}
```

However, whilst the first `element` log spits out the HTML of the node, the second one that should be reading the value is always returning `undefined`.

Question is, what is missing here? How do I read the `tier-value` of the target node?

Comment: Can you update your post with a link to documentation or code that implies this should work? I know there are Controller values but I never heard of Target values. However you still can access the value through the `element.dataset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work as you expect, values can only be set on the controlled element.

https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/values

While the docs are probably not as explicit as they could be, they state that values can only be on the controller element in the first paragraph.

I'm actually surprised you are getting anything from `element.tierValue` in the log, maybe this is a typo.

Nonetheless, the simplest way to achieve some extra data on each target is so use data attributes normally, without anything special on the Stimulus side.

### Example code

```html
<form id="subscriptionForm" data-controller="subscription-form" action="/subscriptions">  
  <input type="hidden" name="product" data-subscription-form-target="product">

  <div data-tier="Production" data-subscription-form-target="tier"></div>
  <div data-tier="Test" data-subscription-form-target="tier"></div>
</form>
```

Note, we are not using the `data-<identifier>-<value-name>-value` convention.

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["tier"]

  connect() {
    this.tierTargets.forEach((element) => {
      console.log(element)
      console.log(element.dataset.tier)
    })
  }
}
```

Note, now we are accessing the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) on the target element this time.

Be aware that this will not do any smart parsing of Boolean or Object typed values, it will be up to your code to read the string attributes and convert it to something useful if a string is not suitable.

### Other approaches

A more complex approach could be to attach a controller (`tier`) to each of the target elements, that controller has a value that is parsed for each instance.

Then you access the controller instance via one of these approaches.

1. Use the new Stimulus Outlets system and then put a controller on each target element. https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/outlets
2. Use Stimulus' getControllerForElementAndIdentifier method. Available on the application instance, not sure if documented. https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/blob/main/src/core/application.ts#L80
3. Use DOM events and pass in a callback for the controller that provides the data needed. Likely more complex than its worth.